# Receiving empty bytes array for Imessage.content from Azure service bus

Tags: azure, service, synchronization, bus

I am currently using two different platforms to perform sync actions. So, when action happens on **platform 1 (C# -visual studio)**, that same action then needs to happen on **platform 2 (Java)**. To do that, I use **SB (Azure service bus)** for sharing the Json messages between two platforms.

> Action 1: platform 1 ----> Service bus -----> platform 2 .

**Works fine**. The message is sent and received exactly as it should be.

> Action 2: platform 2 ----> Service bus ----> platform 1.

**Does not work**. The message is sent correctly to SB, but when it's picked up, the content property only contains an empty array, when it should be an array of bytes (containing the message). The other message attributes like contentType, replyTo and so on are set correctly, so the message is getting picked up fine. It's just that there is no content or in other words message body.

> Action 3: Azure SB/Send messages -----> Service bus -----> platform 1.

**Works fine**. Another option is to send the JSON message directly to the Service Bus using Azure Service Bus/Send messages and put the JSON message in there.

For actions 2 and 3 exactly the same message is sent to the service bus (when I view it). One is sent directly to service bus, another is generated by the platform 2. I think the actual message somehow seems to be different in the background, which is why the message body is empty in the action 2.

*Threads and processes are being handled correctly.*

To set up receiver:

```
IMessageReceiver receive r= null;

if (config.isSessionsEnabled()) {
    receiver = ClientFactory.acceptSessionFromConnectionStringBuilder(new ConnectionStringBuilder(connString), config.getSessionID(), ReceiveMode.PEEKLOCK);
} else {
    receiver = ClientFactory.createMessageReceiverFromConnectionStringBuilder(new ConnectionStringBuilder(connString), ReceiveMode.PEEKLOCK);
}
```

For receiving message:

```
try {
       message = receiver.receive(Duration.ofSeconds(1)); //message.Content will be empty array
       if(message != null){
         //process message
       }                    
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Is my understanding correct or perhaps there is another explanation to it!

Answer (score 0):

> Is my understanding correct or perhaps there is another explanation to it!

It is very odd that if you send the message from Java platform and the content  of message is empty.

Based on my understanding, it seems that message content is empty when you send to ABS. I recommand that you could check the Java send message code before sending to ABS.

You alse could use [Azure Service bus exploer](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer) to get the message information after it sent to ABS [*Before received from .Net platform*].